# Flutter Audioplayer Can't get duration in android Devices

Tags: flutter

I am using audioplayers: 0.16.1 version.
It's playing sound but not getting duration and position.
So Slider seek and pause then play is not working.
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update audioplayers: ^0.20.1 ,
code ,
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

```
  audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration d) {
   print('Max duration: $d');
   setState(() => duration = d);
  });
```